# How can we use a service within routing module to have dynamic names for routing paths?

Tags: angular, url-routing

I have a standard routing module for my application. However, since my route names keep changing by my marketing team I want to use a constants driven route names instead of hardcoded ones. To implement the same I made the changes as below:

```
import { NgModule, OnInit }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';

import { CrisisListComponent }   from './crisis-list.component';
import { HeroListComponent }     from './hero-list.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';
import { ConstantsService } from './constants-service.ts';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',        component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule implements OnInit {
  constructor(private const: ConstantsService){}
  const routeNames: Object;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.routeNames = this.const.getRouteNames();
    // The constants service is a plain injectable that returns an object 
    // with key-value pairs for route names
  }
}
```

I am unable to move ahead after this. As `ngOnInit` method itself is not getting called. I tried to export the `AppRoutingModule` in the `@ngModule` declaration but I am getting a stack-oversized error, i.e. I am making a recursive call somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement `OnInit` to an Angular Module as `OnInit` is meant for Components and Directives.

Please Refer [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Does that mean we always have to hardcoded path values in routing? Can you kindly offer a solution for the above problem?

Comment: You may pass parameters in your routing path like `crisis-center/:crisis-id`

Comment: Please refer : Routing With Parameter https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter